# SQL Server 2008 R2 old database data deletion

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

We have the database size around 450 GB. Due to space issue we need to delete the `.mdf` data by date. Please let me know how to delete the data.

Comment: The `mdf` file contains **all** the data and cannot be selectively deleted. Please provide more details of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can target old data from the bigger tables. You can use bulk copy utility to do that where you can export the data to files. This is very fast and you can easily import the data back to the table when required.

You have run this utility from command prompt.

Go to the location where bcp.exe file is present.

Export : 
bcp "SELECT *  FROM big_table where some_date < '2015-12-31' " queryout file_path\big_table_date_range.dat -SServer_Details -UUser_id -Ppwd -n

Import :
bcp some_big_table in file_path\big_table_date_range.dat -SServer_Details -UUser_id -Ppwd -n

Comment: thanks...but it query taking too much time ,we require the daily basis data delete or maintenance plan...is there any option.(SQL Server 2008 r2)

Comment: did u give table partitioning a thought?